# Shell Script - single line - expr command

Tags: shell

I am using this 3 line shell script and it works
to compare 2 files sizes.

```
FIRSTV=`stat -c%s crk03-rtr-002-20140504.rsc`
SECONDV=`stat -c%s crk03-rtr-002-20140503.rsc`
echo `expr $FIRSTV - $SECONDV`
```

If there a way I could do this on 1 line using expr or a better command which can tell me the number of bytes differnce between 2 files?

L

Comment: Why is having three lines a problem?

Comment: Note that ``echo `expr $FIRSTV - $SECONDV` `` produces exactly the same output as `expr $FIRSTV - $SECONDV`; you don't need the echo or back-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do:

```
expr `stat -c%s crk03-rtr-002-20140504.rsc` - `stat -c%s crk03-rtr-002-20140503.rsc`
```

In BASH/ksh/dash and few more shells you can make use of `(( ))` (arithmetic evaluation brackets):

```
echo $(( $(stat -c%s crk03-rtr-002-20140504.rsc) - $(stat -c%s crk03-rtr-002-20140503.rsc) ))
```

Comment: Arithmetic expansion is not bash specific but part of the POSIX standard. Your second line would work with ksh, dash and others. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04